# Need alert for all field in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to get alert for all empty field. In this bellow code, I am able to get alert for username field. how to get alert for all the fields.

JavaScript Code

```
function null_field(form_name, field_name) {
  var field = document.forms[form_name][field_name].value;

  if (field == null || field == "") {
    alert("All Field Are Required");

    return false;
  }
}
```

Login Form

```
<form action="login_code.php" method="post" onSubmit="return null_field('login_form', 'username')" name="login_form">
<b>Username: </b><input type="text" name="username" class="field">
<b>Password: </b><input type="password" name="password" class="field">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: No, I don't no jquery.

Comment: Note that `fields.value` cannot be `null`. There's no need to check for that.

Answer (score 3):

Create a function for the whole form instead:

```
function valid_form(form_name) {
    var form = document.forms[form_name],
        fields = form.elements, i = 0, l = fields.length;
    for (; i < l; i++)
        if (fields[i].value === "") {
            alert("All Field Are Required");
            return false;
        }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why not initialise `i` in the `for` head for consistency? The empty statement looks bad.

Comment: @JanDvorak It's just a stylistic option. First, use just a `var` for all the variables used in a function. But then, why not initialize right away? It's just a matter of personal preferences, though.

Comment: As I said, I don't like `for(; ...`

Comment: Then would you mind me doing `for(;;){...}` and breaking in the middle?

Comment: Note that `fields.value` cannot be `null`.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yeah, too bad copypasta. I also forgot to put `[i]`. By the way, instead of `for (;;)` I'd use `while (true)` (or 1), which is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

For each field, you have to call the function. so, for each input tag, call `onsubmit="not_null"`.

Comment: Needs more detail. How to call it? A code sample would help understanding

Answer (score 0):

I think link will help you what you need. Hope you are looking for same

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/8702/validation-summary-in-javascript.aspx

Comment: Link-only answers are not welcome here. Can you quote the relevant parts here?

Comment: Not that the approach used in the linked resource is one that I find good.

Answer (score 0):

If you need one single alert if there are any empty fields, you can use something like this:

```
function validate_fields(form_name) {      
  var has_empty_fields = false;

  for (var field in document.forms[form_name].elements) { 
    if(field == null || field.value == "") {
      has_empty_fields = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (has_empty_fields) {
    alert("All Fields Are Required");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In raw javascript you could do the following:

```
function null_field(form_name)
  {
    for(i=0; i<document.forms[form_name].elements.length; i++){
       if (document.forms[form_name].elements[i] == null ||document.forms[form_name].elements[i].value == "" || document.forms[form_name].elements.value == undefined)
              {
                  alert("All Field Are Required");
                  return false;
              }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Sooo... where's jQuery? And why do you mention it when Abhijit doesn't use it?